# exim4 nonstandard ports

Tags: smtp, debian, linode, exim

I am trying to use exim4 on debian to relay mail, nothing more.  I have a stage mail server and a production mail server (both written custom in python to do weird stuff).  I also have all these running on a single linode host.

production mail is on port 2500, stage mail is running on port 2501.  I'd like exim to relay  mail based on the target domain to these nonstandard ports.  I can easily get it to recognize the domain, but I can't seem to find any info on how to add port information to the configuration.

Comment: I think this belongs to serverfault, not stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create 2 routers and 2 transports, below configuration could work.

```
domain_list my_relay_2500 = example1.com:example2.com
domain_list my_relay_2501 = example3.com:example4.com

my_relay_2500_router:
 driver = manualroute
 domains = +my_relay_2500
 transport = my_remote_smtp_2500
 route_data = ${lookup{$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/remote_relay.txt}}
 no_more

# after `begin transports`
my_remote_smtp_2500:
  driver: smtp
  port: 2500

my_remote_smtp_2501:
  driver: smtp
  port: 2501
```

File /etc/exim/remote_relay.txt

```
example1.com: 10.0.0.3   my_remote_smtp_2500
example2.com: 10.0.0.3   my_remote_smtp_2500
example3.com: 10.0.0.3   my_remote_smtp_2501
example4.com: 10.0.0.3   my_remote_smtp_2501
```